# Origin, guru name, dhyan of this shiv mantra?

Tags: shiva, mantras, identification-request

I found this mantra from [YouTube](https://youtu.be/ymHMeF_XNpY) :

> Om namo Neelkanthaya Vrishdwajaya namo hoom Fat.

What is the origin, guru name and dhyan of this Shiva Mantra?

Comment: please put reference of the text from which you have taken this mantra?

Comment: @zaxebo1 this mantra is from YouTube video - https://youtu.be/ymHMeF_XNpY

Comment: @Rickross: can you answer this question?

Comment: @zaxebo1: Can you answer this question?

Comment: not sure about text. It seems like to be from Pashupat or aghori tradition text

Comment: @zaxebo1: without dhyana, nyas and mantra creator name, can we get maximum benefit from this mantra